How to render fluids?
I want to make a candle burning animation and i add a cube with smoke and fire and another domain cube, when i bake the animation it shows fine in solid mode after baking it. But when i try to render it the fluid simulation doesn't show up, its just my candle standing all alone. I have baked the animation and I have also checked the camera icon both of the objects have it on to be showed in render mode.
this is image of my animation in solid mode:

And this is the same camera angle but in render mode where the fire wont show up:


Does the domain have a material suitable for fire and smoke? Have you watched any tutorials on how to simulate smoke and fire in Blender?

Thanks for the help man I just started with rendering after watching the 1st video of tutorial. In the second video he shows that you need to add a material and Principled Volume shader node. I was too eager to render it. LOL

That's what I suspected ;) Actually many smoke tutorials start off by selecting an object which they want to use as smoke emitter and then go to the menu Object > Quick Effects > Quick Smoke. If you do this, Blender automatically adds a domain object around the emitter which already has a Principled Volume material. Only when you do it manually (like I usually do as well) you have to assign a material on your own.

yes I also added it manually but now i know a bit better (not with the help of tutorials :) ) Anyways thanks man

So what I did was render it without adding any material to the domain. to see the smoke in rendered view i need to add some material to the domain object and change the output from surface to volume as smoke is a volume. So I deleted the principled BSDF and added Pricipled Volume node and gave it a color. BOOM! now i can see the smoke in rendered view.
